# Passing variable with JavaScript function 

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass variable though the `GetDetail` function below.  I can pass string/number and it works properly.

But I'm unable to pass variable

```
detLink.onclick = new Function ("GetDetails()");
detLink.setAttribute('onclick',"javascript:GetDetails()")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
detLink.onclick = function () { GetDetails ( parameter1, parameter2, ... );  }
```

which is an [anonymous function](http://helephant.com/2008/08/javascript-anonymous-functions/).

Read also [The function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Functions#The_function_expression_%28function_operator%29) (function operator)

A function expression is similar to and has the same syntax as a function declaration

```
function [name]([param] [, param] [..., param]) {
   statements
}
```

> name 
>       The function name. Can be omitted, in which case the function becomes
>   known as an anonymous function.
>
> param 
>       The name of an argument to be passed to the function. A function can
>   have up to 255 arguments.
>
> statements 
>       The statements which comprise the body of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
detLink.setAttribute('onclick',"javascript:GetDetails("+yourVariableName+")")
```

When You set attribute You are using string datatype, thus you have to stitch function name with variable VALUE

Comment: FYI: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-242-setattribute-doesnt-always-work.html

Comment: Not working for IE in instead of localhost i use IP address if i write on Alert in Get detail it doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the variable in question when you set the click handler,

```
detLink.onclick = function() { 
  GetDetails(foo); 
}
```

If you don't,

```
detLink.id = uniqueId;
detLink.onclick = function() {
  var foo = globalData[this.id];
  GetDetails(foo);
}

// somewhere else in your code, where you know the value of the variable
globalData[detLink.id] = foo;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var val1 = "Hell world"
detLink.onclick = GetDetails( val1 );
```

---

```
function GetDetails( myVar ){
   alert ( myVar );
}
```

Comment: this won't work as GetDetails will be called during the declaration and not after the click.